# How to find time taken for a faster object to cross a slower object of same length, both moving parallel to each other in the same direction?

Tags: kinematics, time, velocity, distance

Can you explain me how to determine the time taken for a faster object to cross a slower object when they're both of same length and are moving parallel to each other in the same direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When solving physical problems it is essential to draw diagrams.
This helps to develop a concept in your mind (especially when having
no idea yet about the solution).
Do this before writing down any formulas.

Because your problem is about motion in space let's draw a
space-time diagram ($s$ versus $t$).
Start by drawing the slower object $A$ and the faster object
$B$ at the beginning and at the finishing of the overtaking process.
Because the objects move with constant velocities
their movements appear as straight lines in the $s$-$t$-diagram.

[image]

Then mark the known quantities in the diagram:

- object $A$ has length $\ell$
- object $B$ also has length $\ell$
- object $A$ moves with velocity $v_A$
- object $B$ moves with velocity $v_B$

Then (even more importantly) mark the unknown quantities in the diagram:

- the time $\Delta t$ needed for overtaking
- the distance $\Delta s_A$ travelled by object $A$ during overtaking
- the distance $\Delta s_B$ travelled by object $B$ during overtaking

[image]

Now you are ready to set up up some formulas.
From the definition of velocity you get for object $A$ and $B$
$$v_A=\frac{\Delta s_A}{\Delta t} \tag{1}$$
$$v_B=\frac{\Delta s_B}{\Delta t} \tag{2}$$

Now you have 3 unknowns ($\Delta t$, $\Delta s_A$, $\Delta s_B$),
but only 2 equations (1, 2).
This is obviously not enough.
So you need to find one more equation.
The diagram shows (may be after staring at it for a while)
$$\Delta s_B = \ell + \Delta s_A + \ell \tag{3}$$

So finally you have 3 equations for 3 unknowns.
You should now be able to solve these equations and
find the solution
$$\Delta t=\frac{2\ell}{v_B-v_A}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here you're only trying to find the time taken by this object to cover a distance equal to it's length. So, time=length/speed. Have you been
given the speed and length?

Comment: Yeah, both are 390 metres long. One's speed is 42 km/hr and the one's is 36 km/hr.

Comment: In that case just find the relative velocity and substitute it in place of "speed".

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing @Frost